# Stack crashed when pushed value to a struct

Tags: c

Hey guys im learning c and im currently working on stack, structure and pointer. Im using visual studio to do my the program and whenever i enter my input the program will crash. I'm able to scope down that the error is coming from the product name. I am also quite confused since it includes pointer character. Anyone can point out my mistakes? thank you

## HERE ARE MY CODES

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 10
int top = -1;

struct Product {

    int prodId;
    char *prodName;

};
struct Product arrP[MAX];
struct Product pop();
void push(int id, char *name);
int isFull();
int isEmpty();


struct Product pop()
{
    struct Product temp;

    temp = arrP[top];
    top--;

    return temp;
}

void push(int id, char *name)
{
    top++;
    arrP[top].prodId = id;
    strcpy(arrP[top].prodName,name);
}

int isFull()
{
    if (top == MAX)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int isEmpty()
{
    if (top == -1)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}


int main()
{
    int myID;
    char *myName;

    //Push the value
    printf("Enter the Product id: ");
    scanf("%d", &myID);

    printf("Enter the Product Name: ");
    scanf("%s", &myName);

    push(myID, &myName);
    printf("%d %s", arrP[top].prodId ,arrP[top].prodName);

}
```

Comment: a) `int *myID;` ==> `int myID;` b) `char myName;` ==> `char myName[100];` c) `scanf("%s", &myName);` ==> `scanf("%99s", myName);`

Comment: You need to allocate space for the `prodName` pointer.

Comment: @4386427 doesnt work...

Comment: @500-InternalServerError may i know how do i do that?

Comment: See achal's answer.

Comment: @Dexter Siah: If you haven't learned about dynamic memory allocation yet, you might be better off using `char prodName[SIZE];` instead of `char *prodName;`. (Make sure `SIZE` is large enough to hold your data. E.g., `#define SIZE 64`.)

I think this is maybe what FSOCIETY is suggesting in his answer.

Or is this is an assignment where you are expected to use dynamic memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few simple bugs which you can  avoid my listening to compiler warning while compiling with `-Wall` flag.

**Case 1:-**  variable `myId` suppose to be a integer variable, not a pointer variable. If you want it to be pointer variable then you should allocate memory for it first.

`int *myID;`

`printf("Enter the Product id: ");`

`scanf("%d", &myID);`

Replace with

`int myID;`

`printf("Enter the Product id: ");`

`scanf("%d", &myID);`

**Case 2:-**  variable `myName` supposed to be array of characters as you want to store product name into it.

`char myName;`

`printf("Enter the Product Name: ");`

`scanf("%s", &myName);`

Replace with

`char myName[50];`

`printf("Enter the Product Name: ");`

`scanf("%s", myName);`

While calling `push()` function just pass the `myName`. For e.g

`push(myID, myName);`

Also this statement
`strcpy(arrP[top].prodName,name);`

causes problem as `prodName` is *pointer member in of structure*, you should allocate memory dynamically for  this and then do copy.

`arrP[top].prodName = malloc(SIZE);`

`strcpy(arrP[top].prodName,name);`

Comment: Once use of `arrP[index].prodName` is no more needed, `free` it to avoid memory leakage. Check using `valgrind` .

Answer (score 0):

When you are getting the input using %s  in character type variable, the memory adjacent to the address of the char variable gets overwritten thus can cause program crash. if you want to enter a string, you can try it by defining an array of characters (as char my name[MAX], MAX can be a size suitable to you).